# how to hide json panel on certain dates

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm beginner in ASP NET, I was asked to hide the "Registration Wizard" panel on 2 weeks before and after certain date. I believe we are using JSon to display panels. I'm not sure how can I achieving this as was unable to find anything.

```
    module PrestigeWorldWide.Scripts.ViewModels {
    export class IndexViewModel extends BaseViewModels.BaseViewModel {
        public panels: KnockoutObservableArray<IPanelObject> = ko.observableArray<IPanelObject>();
        public events: KnockoutObservableArray<FullCalendar.EventObject> = ko.observableArray<any>();

        constructor() {
            super();


            this.panels.push({
                Name: "My Transcript",
                Desc: "View your unofficial QUB transcript",
                Icon: "fa-file-text",
                Link: "/PrestigeWorldwide/Grade/ViewTranscript"
            });

            this.panels.push({
                Name: "Module Info",
                Desc: "View the information on all modules including pre-requisites and course content",
                Icon: "fa-folder-open",
                Link: "/PrestigeWorldwide/Module/ModuleInfo"
            });

            this.panels.push({
                Name: "Enrollment Wizard",
                Desc: "Enroll for modules and enter further information about yourself - emergency contacts etc.",
                Icon: "fa-magic",
                Link: "/PrestigeWorldwide/Registration/Index"
            });

            this.getEvents();
        }

        getEvents() {
            var url = "/PrestigeWorldwide/Class/GetStudentClasses";
            this.loading(true);
            $.ajax(url).done((events: FullCalendar.EventObject[]) => {
                this.loading(false);
                _.each(events, (event) => {
                    this.events.push(event);
                });
            });
        }


    }

    export interface IPanelObject {
        Name: string;
        Desc: string;
        Icon: string;
        Link?: string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to hide the panels in the front-end? Please provide us code from the view which calls `GetPanels()`.

Comment: This sounds like a UI issue.. please provide your UI code

Comment: @krilovich - sorry guys! I've been using a wrong script file what so ever... This is the correct code now. I need to hide the panel called Enrollment Wizard in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a date check before adding the panel:

```
DateTime cutOffDateStart = new DateTime() // Insert 2 weeks before here
DateTime cutOffDateEnd = new DateTime() // Insert 2 weeks after here

if (DateTime.Now >= cutOffDateStart && DateTime.Now < cutOffDateEnd) 
{
    panels.Add(new Panel()
    {
        Name = "Registration Wizard",
        Desc = "Use this tool to enrol for the new semester.",
        Icon = "fa-pencil"
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry I've been using a wrong script file what so ever... This is the correct code now. I need to hide the panel called Enrollment Wizard in front end.